# Mysql query process check via Wireshark

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, wireshark, windows-server-2019

I am trying to understand what's happening in the background, when a simple select query executed by client.

I am using C# Asp.Net Webforms, and i checked the processes with WireShark.

[image: enter here]

```
public DBC(string procedureName, params object[] procParams)
{
    strError = null;
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        connection.Close();
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(procedureName, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //if we use params for stored procedure
            if (procParams != null)
            {
                int i = 1;
                foreach (object paramValue in procParams)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@param_" + i, paramValue.ToString()));
                    i++;
                }
            }

            if (procedureName.Contains("get"))
            {
                dtLoaded = new DataTable();
                dtLoaded.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strError = ErrorHandler.ErrorToMessage(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple `SELECT * FROM TABLE` query, in a try-catch statement. At the finally state, the connection was closed and disposed.

Why is it causes 43 process? I don't understand, why is there so much. Somebody could explain me?

Many thanks!

Comment: TCP max datagram size is ~1500 (1514 for this connection) bytes so when the server needs to send more data more responses are required.  The final should end with s 200 OK status.

Comment: Are you doing any parallel request?  It looks like a 2nd request is sent out before the 200 OK from the 1st.

Comment: oh, i see, thanks!. I don't think, this connection request is the only one. I added above the code, what is called if the button clicked. First picture include that processes when the button clicked. (This is an universal db connection handler method, for any type of procedure)

Comment: Pushing the button multiple times will create multiple parallel requests unless you add a lock to prevent multiple requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using Oracle's Connector/NET. It performs a lot of not-strictly-necessary queries after opening a connection, e.g., `SHOW VARIABLES` to retrieve some server settings. (In 8.0.17 and later, this has [been optimised slightly](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93202).)

Executing a stored procedure requires retrieving information about the stored procedure (to align parameters); it's more "expensive" than just executing a SQL statement directly. (You can disable this with `CheckParameters=false`, but I wouldn't recommend it.)

You can switch to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) if you want a more efficient .NET client library. It's been [tuned for performance](https://mysqlconnector.net/#performance) (in both client CPU time and network I/O) and won't perform as much unnecessary work when opening a connection and executing a query. (MySqlConnector is the client library used for the .NET/MySQL benchmarks in the [TechEmpower Framework Benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r18&hw=ph&test=fortune).)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to change to MySqlConnector, and after i'll compare the result.